# Lista de int no delegate Func<> não está funcionando

Tags: c#, delegate

Estou estudando alguma coisa e me deparei com o seguinte problema. Crio uma lista de 7 elementos e trato-a dentro de um Func<> funciona, mas se eu aumento os itens da lista, aí o meu método não funciona como deveria. Isso aí:
Esse é o código que funciona:

```
List<int> lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

            Func<List<int>, int, bool> f = (itens, item) =>
            {
                if (itens != null && itens.Count > 6)
                {
                    int soma = 0;
                    itens.ForEach(it => soma += it + item);
                    return soma % 2 == 0;
                }
                return false;
            };

            var i = from item in lista
                    where f(lista, item)
                    select item;

            i.ToList().ForEach(ite => listBox1.Items.Add(ite));
```

Porem se eu altero a lista, colocando mais dois itens ou um e se deixo o Count > 6 ou altero ele, mesmo assim não funciona o código. O resultado no listbox deveria ser somente dígitos pares. Abaixo não funciona, vem os dígitos ímpares e não pares como eu gostaria. O que devo fazer para isso funcionar? Se eu colocar o dígito "0", aí não preenche nada na listbox. Só quero entender.

```
List<int> lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            Func<List<int>, int, bool> f = (itens, item) =>
            {
                if (itens != null && itens.Count > 7)
                {
                    int soma = 0;
                    itens.ForEach(it => soma += it + item);
                    return soma % 2 == 0;
                }
                return false;
            };

            var i = from item in lista
                    where f(lista, item)
                    select item;

            i.ToList().ForEach(ite => listBox1.Items.Add(ite));
```

Comment: Seu código não adiciona números pares. Ele adiciona números cujas combinações de uma soma acumulada mais um par de números dê um resultado par. Acredito que o problema seja a fórmula matemática utilizada.

Comment: obrigado @Renan, em realidade eu não entendi ou não entendo essa linha: `itens.ForEach(it => soma += it + item);`, bem sei que é um foreach dentro de uma lambda, mas porque somar a variável lambda à variável soma e item, isso é que eu não estou entendendo e acho que é esse o problema.

Comment: Qual o resultado certo e o errado? Tem certeza que precisa usar LINQ? Mesmo que use, precisa criar essa `Func<>`? Se você adicionou 2 porque só aumentou um na condição? Acho que seria melhor descrever o que precisa, porque este código é confuso demais. O que é esta soma? Você quer só os pares que existem na lista? Ou é outra coisa? Assim resolve? https://dotnetfiddle.net/hjUUqg

Comment: @bigown, a questão é que eu estou estudando sobre delegates e isso são exercícios das aulas que pego. O resultado correto pra mim, é o entendimento de tudo isso. Se é par ou ímpar, não importa, o que eu quero é entender isso e quando for arguido, ter uma resposta correta.

Comment: @pnet você fez este código ou ele foi mostrado para você (mesmo o primeiro)?

Comment: @bigown e todos os demais, bom dia. Esse código me foi mostrado.

Comment: Posso fazer isso de várias formas, mas o objetivo é entender e porque o autor colocou a variável lambda na soma, porque isso: `it => soma += it + item`

Comment: @pnet `it` é o iterador da lista que vc colocou como primeiro parâmetro de entrada  da Func<>, então o valor de it será de 1 à 9 em todas as chamadas de f(lista, item). A variável `item` será o segundo parâmetro de entrada da Func<>, seu valor será 1 na primeira chamada de f(lista, item) e então, incrementado a cada chamada. O que acontece realmente nessa linha é a soma de cada inteiro da lista com `item`, isto é, a variável `soma` guardará o resultado do foreach.